# OSX: Stop CDROM spinup during Open or Save

Tags: macos, mac, optical-drive, compact-disc

If there's a CD in my Macbook's drive, it spins up any time I invoke the Open or Save dialog in an application.  And while it spins up, it freezes the application for about 5 seconds!

How do I make it stop?

Comment: I don't think you can make it stop.

Comment: Why does it spin on Save? You can't save to CDs. Bugs me since 10.3